# How would you refer to someone by "my little deer" in (Brazilian) Portuguese?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução

How could I ask the following question, addressed to a young woman?

> "Are you alright my little deer?"

Comment: Do you really mean "deer", or should it be "dear"?

Answer (score 2):

There are uncountable possible variations (just as in English), but base options include:

- *Você está bem, querida?* ("Are you alright, dear?")
- *Tudo bem com você, querida?* ("Is everything OK with you, dear?")

Now, "querida" could be substituted by a number of endearment words, with the best choice dependent on dialect, context and intonation, as well as intention and personal preferences. Some standard choices are "queridinha" ("little dear", perhaps for natural for children), "minha cara" ("(my) dear"), "amor" ("love"), "bebê" ("baby"), etc.